# Checking if hashed values are the same

Tags: java, security, hash, equals

I am using SHA-256 to hash user token, then I am saving that hash value to db , finally when new tokens reaches i am pulling the one i saved previously and checking just with equals method, is that fine? or byte[] needs to be checked differently somehow?

short `if (!Arrays.equals(hashedToken, tokenEntity.get().getToken()))`

```
 private byte[] hashToken(String token) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        return digest.digest(token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No such algorithm exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works, but it could be improved. If I understood it correctly an attacker could steal an open session of a user, if he would be able to guess the hashed user token.

Your current comparison returns false, as soon as the first byte is not equal. So an unequality on an earlier position returns faster than a difference on a later position. An attacker could use a timing attack on the response time to reverse engineer the current token. Therefore you should use a slow equals method, that always compare all bytes in the array and always spends the same time to compare the values.

```
private static boolean slowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    int diff = a.length ^ b.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
        diff |= a[i] ^ b[i];
    }
    return diff == 0;
}
```

here is a good ready about hasing and security: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm
also explaining the timing attack problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, i am actually facing issues, i have hashed two values and then check them in the if block  condition 

if (!Arrays.equals(hashedToken, tokenEntity.get().getToken()))

for some reason even if both tokens are equals it goes inside the body and i have no idea why .

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

[`Arrays.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(byte%5B%5D,byte%5B%5D)) does an element-for-element comparison. Quoting the javadoc:

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of bytes are equal to one another. Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null.

Comment: This is weird then because once i hashed one token and hashed  totally different one its still go inside the if block and the condion is
if (Arrays.equals(tokenEntity.get().getToken(), hashedToken))

Comment: @okey1992 notice the last sentence of the spec:  _two array references are considered equal if both are null_ - if you're sure they were different, almost certainly both tokens were null. Either that or `hashedToken` was *actually* assigned the token from tokenEntity. Use a debugger to step through the code and find out what's going on.